# cordova permission denied on mac terminal

Tags: ios, angular, cordova

I installed globaly cordova and already get the path when I type which cordova, it show cordova: aliased to /Users/myusername/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin

but when I type cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld, it got response as zsh: permission denied: /Users/myusername/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin

then I tried type sudo chown -R myusername /Users/myusername/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin
but it got response as zsh: permission denied: /Users/myusername/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin when I type cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld again.

how to repair it so I can create new ios cordova project from my angular app?

Answer (score 0):

I type npm config set prefix /usr/local, and then after enter I type npm install -g cordova and enter again. the I can got cordova --version. It starting create new project when I type cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld. 
that is the solution for me. Hope this can help other.

Answer (score 0):

After having the issue above when trying to install it globally, I tried locally and it worked. Simply type the following on Terminal:
`npm install cordova`